# plotting the histogram of data points

Tags: matlab, statistics

Please consider this sample code:

```
figure
data = [0,2,9,2,5,8,7,3,1,9,4,3,5,8,10,0,1,2,9,5,10];
hist(data)
```

Why this histogram plots the data points 0 & 1 with frequency 4 (on Y-axis),when in fact 0 & 1 appear two times in data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 21 data points. By default [hist](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) uses 10 bins. if u execute your [hist](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) as follows:

```
figure
data = [0,2,9,2,5,8,7,3,1,9,4,3,5,8,10,0,1,2,9,5,10];
hist(data, 21)
```

you will get correct answer:

[image]

Comment: I prefer to use `hist(data, 0:10)` in a case like this to explicitly declare 11 bins. Not sure why you are calling for `21`? It looks like you are (deliberately or accidentally) creating additional bins in between the main ones - i.e. you have a bin [0 0.5>, [ 0.5 1>, etc., and every other bin has counts in it… It so happens that corresponds to 21 bins (not the same as "21 data points", which is why I am wondering if this is accidental or deliberate).

Comment: @Floris I provided example for the data in the question and using addition bins allow for nice separation of data. But more generalized example would be useful as well.

Comment: @Marcin:thanks,and yes using 21 bins allow for nice separation of data.

Comment: @Marcin I get that - but the choice of 21 bins for 21 data points, while correct in this instance, might make one think that `hist(data,numel(data))` would be the right thing to do - which it clearly isn't. That was the point I tried to make.

Answer (score 1):

If you did

```
[hy hx] = hist(data)
```

you would see the bins used in the `hx` variable. If you don't specify the bins, they get specified for you - and the default is not very intelligent.

If you have integer data, and you want integer bins,

```
hist(data, min(data):max(data))
```

is a pretty good way to get it. If you need bins greater than 1, something like

```
n = 5;
hist(data, (floor(min(data)/n):ceil(max(data)/n))*n)
```

would work quite nicely, and give you a bin size of n (5, in this case)

Answer (score 0):

N = HIST(Y) bins the elements of Y into 10 equally spaced containers  and returns the number of elements in each container.  If Y is a matrix, HIST works down the columns. Here for 0 and 1 a single bin is made,so histogram plots the data points 0 & 1 with frequency 4 (on Y-axis),when in fact 0 & 1 appear two times in data